# uncheck checkbox and publish in Sitecore

Tags: powershell-extensions

How can we uncheck a checkbox like "upload to cloud cdn" for Sitecore media library and republish it in Sitecore using powershell? Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sitecore stores checkbox value as bool, so if you want to uncheck a checkbox then you need to set the value empty or 0, see below sample code

```
$item.Editing.BeginEdit()
$item.Fields["upload to cloud cdn"].Value = 0
$item.Editing.EndEdit()
```

here you first need to get the $item.

And to check the checkbox you can update the field with value 1.

**Updates**:
To publish the item you can use the `Publish-Item` command and based on your requirement you can publish a single item, a single item with child items with different publishing targets and publishing modes. See - https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/common/publish-item

Comment: But needs to republish also.